# Chinese Characters PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, encoding, phpmailer, decoding

I'm using PHPMailer to send email from PHP. My email body contains HTML format and Chinese characters.

Chinese Characters are not shown correctly, it's changed to strange characters. I take the characters from database. It's shown perfectly if I view through web browser.

What variable of PHPMailer I have to initialize to solve this?

Any helps would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just to make sure, the email client is able to display Chinese characters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably use wrong encoding for HTML body. 
Some important properties are:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->MsgHTML($your_html_body);
$mail->CharSet="UTF-8"; // <-- Put right encoding here
```

Comment: is the order of the variables important?